# SharePoint 2013 workflow task gets canceled

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I have installed and configured sSharePoint 2013 workflow manager according to the instructions on msdn. When i create a simple workflow in SharePOint designer, just one task, the task gets canceled and this error message appears:

RequestorId: 07d0dc78-24ac-7c71-78a3-fcefb293ccf8. Details: System.ArgumentException: ContentTypeId at Microsoft.Activities.Hosting.Runtime.Subroutine.SubroutineChild.Execute(CodeActivityContext context) at System.Activities.CodeActivity.InternalExecute(ActivityInstance instance, ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager) at System.Activities.Runtime.ActivityExecutor.ExecuteActivityWorkItem.ExecuteBody(ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager, Location resultLocation)

Does anybody know what the problem is?

Thanks
//Joakim

Comment: Me too, I have much more items ,only one item error

Answer (score 4):

This issue is caused by the fact that content type that is used for workflow task was not added to workflow task list.

**To fix it:**

1. Check the name of task content type that is used in workflow.
2. Check which list is assigned as "Task list" for workflow.
3. Go to workflow task list > list settings > content types section and
   verity you task content type is present.

If your task content type is not present in the list - just add it :)

**First:**

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DYkxG.png]

**Second:**

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/EjGmx.png]

Comment: Link to the task setting screen: [link](http://i.stack.imgur.com/GYOMa.png)

Comment: I am getting the same above error, however list and content type are perfectly associated, any other thing need to check?

Answer (score 1):

We had the same issue.  It is a bug in the latest SharePoint update.  MS says it will be fixed in June in an update.  I cannot believe they have released an update with such a big bug.